# use Oracle DECODE function select phone_number with the same column in two tables

Tags: sql, oracle, decode

#### Tables:

### table_a

```
user_id | phone_number|state|...|
```

### table_b

```
user_id | phone_number | ...|
```

#### conditions:

1. Must use the Oracle DECODE function to implement SQL statement .
2. If `table_b.phone_number` is not empty ,use `table_b.phone_number` or else if `table_a.state=3` use `table_a.phone_number`
3. `table_a` and `table_b` are joined by `user_id`

#### result:

select all the `user_id` , `phone_number` mapping result like

```
user_id | phone_number
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Look like homework...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
select a.user_id,
      decode(b.phone_number,
             null,
             decode(a.state,
                    3,
                     a.phone_number),
      b.phone_number) phoneNumber 
     from table_a a,
          table_b b 
where a.user_id=b.user_id(+)
```

Comment: why (+) in  a.user_id=b.user_id(+)

Comment: There is nothing in question to indicate a LEFT JOIN is necessary.

Comment: Also this solution is wrong because it prioritises A.PHONE_NUMBER over B.PHONE_NUMBER, whereas the question clearly states that B should be used if it if exists

Answer (score 1):

Why must you use `DECODE()`? It is not suitable for implementing your requirement. `CASE()` is the correct solution.

```
select a.user_id
       , case 
             -- condition 1
             when b.phone_number is not null then b.phone_number
             -- condition 2
             when a.state = 3 then a.phone_number
             -- conditions not met
             else 'no phone'
          end as phone_number
from a 
     join b on a.user_id = b.user_id
```

This could be done with `decode()` but how clunky is this?

```
 decode(b.phone_number
         , null
         , decode(a.state
                   , 3
                   , a.phone_number
                   , 'no phone')
         ,  b.phone_number) as phone_number
```

Comment: Looks like a homework question. That's why `DECODE` is compulsory.

Comment: @Nitish - you're probably right. This site is littered with students asking for solutions to wrong-headed assignments :(

Answer (score 0):

use NVL with DECODE:

`select a.user_id,
       nvl(b.phone_number, 
           decode(a.state,3,a.phone_number,null)) phone_no
from table_a a left join table_b b on a.user_id = b.user_id`